Why does this uninitialized boolean variable always start at 0?
First of all I know that this is UB and technically anything could happen. But regarding this code snippet compiled with -O0 for target x86_64-linux-gnu, why does this never print "truthy"?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int test(void) 
{
    bool value;
    if (value)
    {
        printf("truthy");
    }
    printf("Value: %d", value);
}

int main(void)
{
    double buffer[80000];
    buffer[10] = 0;
    test();
}

Godbolt
I would expect value to be basically random, what am I missing?
EDIT: I'm talking about C here, but if there are any differences with C++ I'm interested in those as well.

Because it happened to hold that value already. Local variables are not initialised. It might always be true on another platform, or inconsistent on another. Duplicate: Why local variable is initialized to zero. Also see Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior.

When memory is assigned to a process it's normally zeroed to ensure it doesn't contain the values that another process was using, since that would be a security problem. If the stack frame hasn't been used for anything else yet, it will naturally contain that zeroed memory.

Uninitialized doesn't mean random, as in randomized from run to run. It is just whatever value that happened to be in that place in memory at that time, but it's your process memory, it is unlikely to get shuffled around every run.
BTW, the way it usually gets you is a month (year, 10 years...) later, everything works, and then you add a totally unrelated code that just happened to shift stuff around, and that uninitialized variable just happened to change value, in which case, well... happy debugging ;-)

You're confusing "undefined behavior" with "random behavior".  There's no random number generator that gets consulted whenever undefined behavior is invoked, and in fact undefined behavior isn't really random.  In a given program, built with a given compiler on a given system, it will quite likely do the same thing each time it's run in some specific way.  But it often takes very little for that behavior to change.  In your case, the functions that were called before this one can affect it, by leaving different values on the stack.  Who knows?  You can always look at the compiled code.

BTW, this is indeed undefined behaviour (When is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?) instead of an "indeterminate value" because bool value; could have been declared register bool value;.  I don't know why the C standard makes that the criterion for fully UB vs. "just" an indeterminate value, but it does.

"l I know that this is UB..." "why..." - It seams you don't understand UB at all. After realizing UB, why things are happening are moot. You can find reasons in the sourse code of the implementation you use to compile, and that may change the at any time.

@TedLyngmo: The actual practical reasons for what happens in a given build are much easier to find by looking at the assembly for the binary the compiler actually made for this input (and the OS behaviour of zeroing memory to avoid info leaks between processes), not looking at the GCC source code!  Also, to be fair, knowing that something is UB (because you checked the C standard) gives you zero information about how different cases of UB are likely to behave in different real programs.  I guess you could say the OP doesn't understand UB in those terms, but that's why they're asking.

@PeterCordes Fair enough. However, looking at the assembly wouldn't be my first choice, or, perhaps, it'd be a just a first glance. Then I'd be looking at the implementation to get a more general feeling for how that kind of UB could manifest itself using that implementation.


I would expect value to be basically random, what am I missing?

When the C standard says the behavior is undefined, it means only that the C standard does not specify anything about the behavior. In particular, it says nothing about whether anything else specifies or affects the behavior.
The absence of a statement about what something does is not a valid reason to infer it would be random.
In general-purpose multiuser systems, when a process requests memory, it is generally provided in two ways (perhaps excepting special requests): For code or initialized data, it is read from the executable file of the program into memory. For uninitialized data, the operating system usually cannot provide uninitialized memory. This is because memory is shared by processes: It is at one time used by one process and later used by another process. The operating system has an obligation to keep the data of processes confidential (unless they specifically request to share memory). So, whenever the operating system gives memory to a process, it must initialize it to non-sensitive data. That is most often done by setting all of it to zero.
So, when a process starts in such a system, the memory used for its stack and for other uninitialized data will actually contain zeros. When a C program starts, there is some initialization code that executes before the main routine. That code may use some of the stack for its own purposes, so, when main is called after that initial code, not everything on the stack will be zero. So, if you attempt to observe the values of uninitialized objects on the stack at the start of your program, you may see some of them have non-zero values, but zero values will be very common.
Later in your program, after various routines have been called and have returned, your stack will have been used for multiple purposes, leaving behind a variety of data, and it is less likely that uninitialized objects on the stack will appear to have zero values.
This is an important lesson: While the C standard does not specify the behavior here, the behavior is affected by requirements of the operating system, by how the C environment is implemented, and by other factors. It is usually not random; it largely a consequence of things we can learn about.
